# 27.0.0 is not a valid SDK Version. Option are 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0 Unversioned

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't run my app using expo android application. My device working on Android Pie (8).

Expo android  app version: 2.11.10

I trying run application on another device but have the same issue

[error screen](https://i.ibb.co/Dt5ShJc/photo-2019-06-02-13-07-19.jpg)
27.0.0 is not a valid SDK Version. Option are 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0 Unversioned

my package.json looks as below:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.55.21",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.1",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.2",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/expo": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.116",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "native-base": "^2.5.2",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.486",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.31",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
  }
}
```

app.json looks like:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Tream",
    "slug": "Tream",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "icon": "./src/assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./src/assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.treamcompany.tream"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": ["ts", "tsx"],
      "transformer": "node_modules/react-native-typescript-transformer/index.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your expo version:

1. npm install (for node module)
2. expo update
3. npm install react-native-gesture-handler --save
4. npm start

I had the same issue but i run the above commands and got the output

Answer (score 0):

You can see the explanation for why this happened here: https://blog.expo.io/updated-expo-client-available-on-app-store-and-play-store-8747bd3a1364

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:
"in your app.json and package.json files the sdk version should be the same"

```
 "expo": {
"name": "ThirdReactApp",
"slug": "Third-React-App",
"privacy": "public",
"sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
"platforms": [
  "ios",
  "android"
],
```

---

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The Expo client on your device is probably uptodate and fine but its the app (project) that you are trying to load thats outdated. You simply need to update your app (project) to a more recent and more compatible sdk. That said, follow the instructions on this website for a step by step guide on how to do this.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Answer (score 0):

For 27.0.0,You can use Expo apk 2.10.6

https://d1ahtucjixef4r.cloudfront.net/Exponent-2.10.6.apk